# Notify network status in same activity using Receivers

Tags: android

I am working with google chat application

When chatting if network fails, I have to notify user that network disconnected and if network connected again i have to notify network connected in the same activity.But not worked out

Following is the code which I written:

```
public class GTChat extends ListActivity


 {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}




private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
{
   @Override

 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

 {


 boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

 NetworkInfo info = (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO); 

 if (info.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) 

    { 

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   } 

else
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Network not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

  }

   }

};



protected void onPause()

{


unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver); 


super.onPause();


}


protected void onResume()

{

registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));


super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to use service to detect network status in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405504/how-to-use-service-to-detect-network-status-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

call the super.onResume()/super.onPause() before to register/unregistering receiver.

```
  protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver); 
    }


    protected void onResume()
    { 
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));

    }
```